# Check if process is running on multiple remote computers and copy a file if process is NOT running, keep list of those which succeeded

Tags: powershell

I need to copy a file to multiple computers, but can only do so if a particular app (process) is not running.

I know I can use Invoke-Command to run a script (scriptblock) on a list of machines.

But how can I check if process is running on the machine and then only copy file if it is not running.

So that at the end of running against a load of computers I can easily see those which succeeded e.g. process was not running and file was copied

Thanks

UPDATE:

I am assuming something like this will do the first bits of what I am asking, but how to visually show or log success or failure so I know which computers have been done - doesn't need to be anything fancy, even if simply a variable that holds computername of those where process wasn't running and file was copied okay

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName PC1, PC2, PC3 -ScriptBlock {

If ((Get-process -Name notepad -ea SilentlyContinue) -eq $Null){

   Copy-Item -Path "\\server01\c$\test\file.txt" -Destination "C:\test\file.txt" -Force

}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$Procs = invoke-command -ComputerName PC1 { get-process | Select Name }
    If($Procs -notmatch "Notepad"){  Copy-Item -Path "\\server01\c$\test\file.txt" -Destination "\\$PC1\c$\test\" -Force}
```

edited:

```
$computers = @("PC1","PC2","PC3")
    Foreach($computer in $computers){
$Procs = invoke-command -ComputerName $computer { Get-Process Notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
    If(!$Procs){"$Computer - not running Notepad"; Copy-Item -Path "\\server01\c$\test\file.txt" -Destination "\\$computer\c$\test\" -Force}
    elseif($Procs){"$Computer - is running Notepad"}
    }
```

Edit2(for clean output):

```
$computers = @("PC1","PC2","PC3")
$RNote = @()
$NNote = @()
$off   = @()

    Foreach($computer in $computers){
$TestC = Test-Connection -ComputerName $computer -Count 1
    If(!($TestC)){$off += $computer} Else{

$Procs = invoke-command -ComputerName $computer { Get-Process Notepad -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue}
    If(!$Procs){$NNote +=$computer; Copy-Item -Path "\\server01\c$\test\file.txt" -Destination "\\$computer\c$\test\" -Force}
    elseif($Procs){$RNote +=$computer}
    }
}

$leng =[array]$RNote.count,$NNote.Count,$off.count
[int]$max = ($leng | measure -Maximum).Maximum
    for($i=0; $i -lt $max;$i++){
[pscustomobject]@{
    "Notepad On"  = $(if ($RNote[$i]){$RNote[$i]})
    "Notepad Off" = $(if ($NNote[$i]){$NNote[$i]})
    "Offline "    = $(if ($off[$i]){$off[$i]})
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you - that works perfectly for copying file if notepad not open, but I need to some how record results so I know which computers worked and which didn't?

Comment: Your edited version seems to think notepad is both open and close - result I get is "PS C:\Users\administrator.LB> C:\Tmp\PCA_TESTING_ONLY\file_copy.ps1
NO-IT - not running Notepad
NO-IT - is running Notepad"

Comment: Thanks for edit - that now shows correct information, BUT it doesn't seem to correctly detect if notepad is open, as it says not running and copies file even if it is open? any ideas please?

Comment: updated it, should just give you a nicer output!(:

Comment: Ran first time and worked fine - thanks, but then tried to run it again and get odd error "Could not compare "0" to "1". Error: "Cannot convert the "System.Object[]" value of type "System.Object[]" to type 
"System.Int32"."
At C:\Tmp\PCA_TESTING_ONLY\file_copy.ps1:13 char:15
+     for($i=0; $i -lt $max;$i++){
+               ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ComparisonFailure"

Comment: The error happens only when notepad is open, works fine when closed

Comment: One other issue, if you try adding a computer to $computers which doesn't exist or is turned off, you get error as expected, but it then assumes it is "notepad" off and adds it to that column

Comment: You can try adding a `Test-Connection` to filter those that are offline

Comment: okay, but what about the error when notepad is open I put above?

Comment: Have you ran it now? Can you post the error if it returns one again

Comment: Sorry, hadn't noticed you had updated code - the results are showing oddly now - e.g. Notepad On Notepad Off Offline 
---------- ----------- --------
$RNote[$i] $NNote[$i]  $off[$i]

Comment: Sorry, forgot to expand the string

Comment: Absolutely perfect, thank you so much Abraham

Comment: Hi again - one final issue - if it can't see the computer e.g. host doesn't exist or not found etc you get error "Test-Connection : Testing connection to computer 'Tfdffdd' failed: No such host is known" which then means it can't show results correctly at the end - any ideas please, think Test-Connection needs to handle errors as well as failed pings

Comment: Okay think got that bit working by adding -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue to end of Test-Connection line.  But found another issue, on some computers even though Test-Connection can connect I still can't Invoke-Command as remoting not enable / or they are on public network etc.  So I need to add in a second check which runs below and if that fails add it to a new variable called $RemotingFail, worked out how to do check, but can't seem to combine both methods

Comment: $TestRemote = Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computer { 1 } -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

If(($TestRemote -ne 1)){$remotingfail += $computer} Else{

Comment: did that fix it for you? You may want to ensure winrm is running on those machines

Comment: Hi, I changed the existing Test-Connection method with the one in my last reply which tries to connect so answers if they can be accessed with winrm, but this slows down the process quite a lot, so I would like to do both checks, so first it does Test-Connection, if that fails it adds to $off, then it tries my check above and if that fails it adds to $remotingfail.  And if both pass then it does existing code, just can't seem to work out how to check both one at a time.   I also tried Test-WSMan but that passes the test even on computers I can't connect too, hence using the code I did

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you're looking for or at least close:

```
$Results = @()

$Results += 
  Invoke-Command -ComputerName DellXPS137000, DellXPS8920 -ScriptBlock {

    $GPArgs = @{Name        = "Notepad++"
                ErrorAction = "SilentlyContinue"}
    If ( $Null -ne (get-process @GPArgs )) {
      #Process your copy here
      $Status = "Success"
    }
    Else {$Status = "Failed"}
  
    $Machine = 
      (Get-CimInstance -ClassName 'Win32_OperatingSystem').CSName
    Return ,"$Machine : $Status"

  }
```

Value of $Results:

```
PS> $results
DELLXPS137000 : Success
DELLXPS8920 : Failed
```

HTH

Comment: Thank you for response, looks exactly like what I need.  But having problems with the file copy part   -    Copy-Item -Path "\\server\file.txt" -Destination "C:\folder\file.txt" -Force     -   doesn't work

Comment: change your `copy-item` line to this: `Copy-Item -Path "\\server01\c$\test\file.txt" -Destination "\\$PC1\c$\test\" -Force`. Its just the incorrect syntax. Use `Get-Help Copy-Item` to see how its supposed to be done. Youre basically telling it to copy over an existing file on your machine.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala - yes your path using c$ works fine, but I was responding to RetiredGeek, and using his method there isn't a variable to use for $computer - hence why tried it with c:\